# Estimating complexity by summation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I have the following simple algorithm which I want to estimate its complexity using summation method, so to speak.

> ```
> count = 0;
> ```
>
> for (k=1; k<=n; k=k*2)
>
> ```
>   for (j=1; j<=k; j=j*2)
>    count++;
> ```

I first started writing 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n  {\sum_{j=1}^k 1
}$$
But then I realized that actually  j is increasing such that 1 2 4 8 16,
So I thought I should replace k with log k!
So I got 
$$\sum_{k=1}^n  log k $$
and then I realized that k has the same manner so I thought, it should be  something like that 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{log n}  log k $$

Is any of what I am doing correct ?If yes, what should I do next ?
If no, what should I have done?

A note: all logs are of base 2

Comment: Why replace with log k and not k?

Comment: I thought moving from 1 to k by incrementing  j  by 1 each time might equal to moving from j to log k by multiplying j by 2 in each iteration; I am probably wrong.

Comment: Ah I see, but you are not summing from j=1 to k, you'd be summing to the floor of the log I believe.

Comment: In the first summation I summed from j=1 to log k. In the second one I summed from k=1 to log n both of which I am not sure about

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with the inner loop (with $j$ iterating until it reaches $k$). As you correctly stated, the loop will execute $\log k$ times, each iteration taking 1 unit of time to execute the count++ operation. So we get

$$\rm Time_{inner-loop}(k)=\log k$$.

Your outer loop runs $\log n$ times, that is correct. However, the value $k$ you used in the algorithm is *not* running from 1 to $\log n$, it is doubled each time, so starts at one but ends at $n$ (or the largest power of 2 that is smaller than or equal to $n$). So the complexity of the whole algorithm is

$$\rm Time_{whole-loop}(n) = \sum_{r=1}^{\log n} {\rm Time_{inner-loop}(2^r)}.$$

Each time you enter the inner loop, your value of k in the algorithm has been doubled from the previous outer iteration, that's why it is $2^r$. If you plug in the time of the inner loop from above, you get

$$\rm Time_{whole-loop}(n) = \sum_{r=1}^{\log n} {\log (2^r)} = \sum_{r=1}^{\log n} {r}.$$

Now you can see, if you replace $r$ with $k$, that your formula is incorrect.

You made the error of mentally substituting $\log k$ for $k$ when counting the iterations in the inner loop, but then forgetting that the $k$ value that goes into the loop is actually $k$, not $\log k$.

In other words, assuming $n=2^{100}$, when the last iteration of the outer loop happens, your value $k$ is equal to $2^{100}$, *not* equal to $100$. In the inner loop, $j$ must be doubled from 1 up to $2^{100}$, which takes $100=\log 2^{100}=\log n$ iterations, as the last summand from the above formula shows.

How to proceed? The formula is the sum of integers from 1 to some value ($\log n$). If you need help, feel free to ask.